# Android Manipulating Shared Preferences - updating value

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to update a counter in my Shared Preferences on android.
I have a property "coin count" which I would like to manipulate, so far I have managed to use "Shared Preferences" to save the coin value after the application is closed but i cannot manipulate these values. 
I want the application to take the old coin count and add it to the new coin count. However the value is just overwritten

My method to save the coins:

```
private void saveCoins(){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = coins.edit();
    int newScore = score/10;
    editor2.putInt("coinNum", score);
    editor2.apply();
}
```

I retrieve the coin count as following:

```
TextView coinDisp = findViewById(R.id.coinDisp);
final SharedPreferences coins = getSharedPreferences("game", MODE_PRIVATE);
coinDisp.setText("Coins: " + coins.getInt("coinNum", 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to do so:

```
    public void saveCoins(String key, int value)
    {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor3 = coins.edit();
        editor3.putInt("coinNum", value + coins.getInt("coinNum", 0));
        editor3.commit();
    }
```